# dynamic link library in c can not find -lmean

Tags: c, dll

The code for the library:

calc_mean.c

```
//#include <stdio.h>

double mean(double a, double b) {
  return (a+b) / 2;
}
```

The header file:

calc_mean.h

```
double mean(double, double);
```

The programm using the library:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calc_mean.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  double v1, v2, m;
  v1 = 5.2;
  v2 = 7.9;

  m  = mean(v1, v2);

  printf("The mean of %3.2f and %3.2f is %3.2f\n", v1, v2, m);

  return 0;
}
```

I created static library using following commands:

```
gcc -c calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o
ar  rcs libmean.a      calc_mean.o
```

Linking against static library:

```
gcc -static main.c -L. -lmean -o statically_linked
```

everything works perfectly fine as long as its static library...

Now these are the commands which I used to create shared library:

```
gcc -c -fPIC calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o   
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmean.so.1 -o libmean.so.1.0.1  calc_mean.o
```

after these two commands when I enter the linkng command

```
gcc main.c -o dynamically_linked -L. -lmean
```

I am  getting error message can not find -lmean
ld returned 1 exit status

attaching error message here

[image]

can some one give me steps to create DLL in C?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating a file named `libmean.so.1.0.1`, but you ask the linker to link with `libmean.so` (this is what -lmean expands to).

You need a symbolic link `libmean.so` pointing to `libmean.so.1.0.1`.

Comment: gcc -c -fPIC calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o   
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmean.so.1 -o libmean.so.1.0.1  calc_mean.o            instead of this, i used these commands gcc -c -fPIC calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o   
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmean.so -o libmean.so  calc_mean.o    but am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

When you try to link the lib by giving `-lmean`, it automatically searches for `libmean.so`, but you have created the lib as `libmean.so.1.0.1`. This is the problem. Either change the lib name or create a symbolic link.

Comment: gcc -c -fPIC calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o   
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmean.so.1 -o libmean.so.1.0.1  calc_mean.o            instead of this, i used these commands gcc -c -fPIC calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o   
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmean.so -o libmean.so  calc_mean.o    but am still getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

Did you copy the libmean.so.1 in /usr/lib/ (or) /opt/lib/?

Comment: Won't help. Wrong answer.